Will using the All-In-One WP Migration tool/plugin affect my live site?
I am about to take over a WordPress site from somebody and need to migrate it from their host to mine.
I am aware of the All-In-One WP Migration tool/plugin and this will be the tool I use.
I want to ask a simple question that I feel could be perceived as silly, yet it is one that I can't seem to find an answer to either.
The question is this: would using the Export to -> File option affect the live site in any way?  My assumption is that it will create a file that I can then use to import the site to my (the new) host; however, I want to also ensure that the live site will still remain active after the file has been created.
I am fairly confident that the site isn't compacted and compressed into the output file, but rather that copies of all files contained within the site will be compressed into the output file.
For those who know, please kindly set my mind at ease! Thank you!

You should contact the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is off topic here.

To be fair, the question is more focused on users' experiences with the plugin, but I'll also reach out to the support team in the interim.

The option that is located in the drop-down “Export to -> File” is not expected to operate on the live site. It is intended for a enduser to make a copy in case his site data and files gets either misplaced, deleted or corrupted. This export usually creates a file that contains all the required data and files which would enable the site to be rebuilt in another location for instance, in a new host. This process does not affect the live site typically, which means that the functionality is retained.

Thank you, this is what I wanted to know. Duly accepted.
